# How to cast array of base class pointer to derived class

Tags: c++, casting

How we could cast an Array of base class pointer to an array of derived class pointer. The following code show an simple example of what i'am trying to do :

```
class CBaseClass
{
    public :
        int CommonValue;
};

class CFirstItem : public CBaseClass
{
    public :
        int firtValue;      
};

class CSecondItem : public CBaseClass
{
    public :
        int secondValue;        
};

class CThirdItem : public CBaseClass
{
    public :
        int thirdValue;     
};


class Manager
{
    public :
        Manager()
        {
            for (unsigned int index = 0; index < 5; ++index)
            {
                m_firstItem[index] = new CFirstItem();
            }
            for (unsigned int index = 0; index < 10; ++index)
            {
                m_secondItem[index] = new CSecondItem();
            }
            for (unsigned int index = 0; index < 12; ++index)
            {
                m_thirdItem[index] = new CThirdItem();
            }
        }

    private :
        CBaseClass* m_firstItem[5];
        CBaseClass* m_secondItem[10];   
        CBaseClass* m_thirdItem[12];    
};
```

My main question here is how could i cast from `CBaseClass` to an `CFirstClass` or `CSecondClass`, i tried

```
CFirstClass* wFirstClass = static_cast<wFirstClass*>(m_firstItem);
```

And that doesn't seems to work, there is any way to how this cast should be made ?

Comment: if you are using polymorphism, you should specify the destructor of the base class as virtual - `virtual ~CBaseClass() = default;`. Also - read about `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast`

Comment: I suppose the second and third loops are inserting element in m_secondItem and m_thirdItem arrays respectively (not in m_firstItem as in your example). But if m_firstItem array contains only pointers on CFirstItem and m_secondItem pointers on CSecondItem and so on, why don't you have pointers of the good type CFirstItem* m_firstItem[5] etc... in which case you don't need any cast.

Comment: Yes you are right i will edit it...

Answer (score 3):

```
CFirstClass* wFirstClass = static_cast<wFirstClass*>(m_firstItem);
```

is wrong since `w_firstItem` decays to `CBaseClass**` in the above expression.

You will be better off if you can design your program such that you don't need to cast. If you must cast, you will need to use `dynamic_cast`.

```
CFirstClass* wFirstClass = dynamic_cast<CFirstClass*>(m_firstItem[0]);
if ( wFirstClass )
{
   // Use the pointer.
}
else
{
   // Deal with other cases
}
```

If you need to cast every pointer in `m_firstItem`, you need to use a loop.

```
for ( auto item : m_firstItem )
{
   CFirstClass* wFirstClass = dynamic_cast<CFirstClass*>(item);
   if ( wFirstClass )
   {
      // Use the pointer.
   }
   else
   {
      // Deal with other cases
   }
}
```

**Update**

@RemyLebeau makes a good point. You should use `dynamic_cast` only if `m_firstItem` holds pointers to different sub-types of `CBaseClass`. In your posted code, since it holds only pointers to `CFirstClass`, it's ok to use `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`:

```
CFirstClass* wFirstClass = static_cast<CFirstClass*>(m_firstItem[0]);
```

The loop version can similarly use `static_cast<CFirstClass*>(item)`.

Comment: Since `m_firstItem[]` contains only `CFirstItem` pointers, the `dynamic_cast` should be replaced with `static_cast`. Same with the other arrays. Using `dynamic_cast` would make sense only if the arrays are merged together into a single array that can hold pointers to different derived types.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, makes sense.

Comment: @RSahu Actually, no. Not What RemyLebeau said but OP's example. It doesn't make sense to use an array of `CBaseClass*` pointers if you're only every going to use it for `CFirstItem*` pointers.

Comment: @n.caillou, we can only speculate why the OP chose to use an array of `CBaseClass*` and chose to store only pointers to objects of type `CFirstItem` in it. I see that they could have used an array of `CFirstItem*` and obviated the need for casting in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply type-cast an array of base pointers to an array of derived pointers.  The pointers will not be pointing at the correct addresses.  If you need an array of derived pointers, you have to create a separate array and type-cast the source items correctly, eg:

```
CFirstClass* wFirstClass[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    wFirstClass[i] = static_cast<CFirstClass*>(m_firstItem[i]);
```

Same with the other arrays:

```
CSecondClass* wSecondClass[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    wSecondClass[i] = static_cast<CSecondClass*>(m_secondItem[i]);
```

```
CThirdClass* wThirdClass[12];
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    wThirdClass[i] = static_cast<CThirdClass*>(m_thirdItem[i]);
```

Comment: @n.caillou: If you type-cast a `CBaseClass*[]` array itself to a `CFirstClass*[]` array, the object pointers WILL NOT be correct. They will still be pointing at `CBaseClass` objects in memory, and will be *misinterpretted* as `CFirstClass` objects when accessed from the casted array. Think of what would happen if you have a `CBaseClass*` pointer misinterpreted as a `CFirstClass*` pointer and you try to access the `firstValue` member. It won't work, it will actually be accessing `CommonValue` instead (if you are lucky). You need a *proper* `CFirstClass*` pointer to a real `CFirstClass` object.

Comment: Oh, I see. If VMT pointers were introduced in the middle of the hierarchy.

Comment: @n.caillou: the issue I have described has nothing to do with VMTs, which only apply to virtual methods, not to data members. Data members are just positive offsets from the start of the declaring class, and at negative offsets from derived classes. So having proper pointers to proper object types is important so the compiler can calculate the offsets correctly. Accessing `CommonValue` from a `CBaseClass*` pointer is different than accessing it from a `CFirstClass*` pointer. `firstValue` can't be accessed from a `CBaseClass*` pointer, only a `CFirstClass*` (or derived) pointer.

Comment: @n.caillou: You need to read up on how polymorphic classes are actually laid out in memory, and how polymorphic pointers actually work.